# ¿Puedo responder igual si otro fue más rápido en responder?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, convenciones-sociales

Me ha pasado ya más de una vez, que cuando estaba redactando una respuesta, se me adelantaron uno o más respondiendo a la pregunta.

Se sabe que para llegar a Roma hay muchos caminos, pero muchas veces, toman todos el mismo camino.

Lo que quiero decir es, si veo que la respuesta del compañero es similar/igual.

- ¿Se puede responder igualmente?
- ¿Sería mejor, por cortesía, de dejar de publicar mi respuesta?
- ¿La diferencia del tiempo transcurrido al que contestó primero, importa también?

---

**Nota:** Mi preocupación es por si lo *reportan como plagio*, por eso en la pregunta sí importa el tiempo transcurrido.

Comment: Yo recomendaría que pongas tu respuesta. Siendo tuya, puede que luego agregues más información que no se cubra en la otra respuesta que en un inicio era igual. Si no tienes más que agregar que lo que está dicho en la otra respuesta (ya publicada) entonces es muy probable que lo mejor sea retractarse y votar a favor de la otra persona que había pensado lo mismo. Recuerda que lo principal en el sitio es ayudar, no la reputación que puedas ganar.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - en verdad no me refería a la reputación.. más bien me preocupaba más por si es reportado por plagio... por eso he preguntado también si el tiempo transcurrido es importante

Comment: Dudo que sea plagio a menos que usen exactamente las mismas palabras, el mismo código, las mismas fuentes a referenciar, etc. Y resalto lo de la reputación porque la publicación es para todo el que la lea, no necesariamente para ti.

Comment: En caso de que la respuesta del compañero sea wiki de comunidad, se puede editarla y ampliarla, complementarla con tu respuesta... De lo contrario no está permitido dar la misma respuesta.

Comment: @ArtEze para mi te equivocas feo, ni esta prohibido ni esta permitido.. libre albedrío. El prohibicionismo que corre por estos días en la comunidad no sirve para nada.. salvo para espantar nuevos usuarios y especialemente expertos que no tienen ganas de lidiar con chiquilinadas como esta. Es solo mi opinion XD

Comment: @EmanuelVe Sé que es complicado llegar a Roma por otro camino, pero sería lo mejor.

Comment: @ArtEze cualquier camino puede recorrerse en linea recta o zigzagueado: tu explicación sera diferente a la mía. tu enfoque servirá a algunos y el mio a otros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "¿Se puede responder igualmente?"

Yo la publicaría igual<sup>1</sup>.

Aunque las dos respuestas sean parecidas y resuelvan la pregunta, una está mejor explicada (o es mas clara) o usa un metodo distinto con el que el OP se siente mas cómodo a la hora de programar, ...

> "¿Seria mejor por cortesía, de dejar de publicar su propia respuesta?"

Como cortesía, si ambas respuestas tienen algo en común, sería mencionar al usuario que posteó la respuesta primero. Ej: "Como bien dice `user987654321` si haces `x` pasa `y` pero añadiendo este código que planteo puedes evitar que ...."

> "¿La diferencia del tiempo transcurrido al que contesto primero, importa también?"

Como dices que durante tu escritura alguien ha publicado, es despreciable. Otra cosa sería publicar algo horas después, sin leer la respuesta ya publicada.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>A menos que ambas respuestas sean **iguales**</sub>

---

Como anecdota de SE:

En [PuzzlingSE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) pasa que el primero en responder (bien) es el que se lleva el tick de aceptada.

Pero claro, para que esté bien no solo tienes que responder bien si no explicar por qué tu respuesta está bien, razonando los puntos que el OP puso de pistas/acertijos ... asi que lo que la gente hace es:

> la respuesta es esta _____ y la explicacion ahora llega.

Entonces asi te aseguras ser el primero, tardes más o menos en escribir detalladamente la explicacion.

Comment: Me parece muy razonable la respuesta...

Comment: Gracias ^^ Es un tema peliagudo el de respuestas identicas. Pero en tu caso, de ser simultaneas es mucho mas ... inocente la situacion

Comment: Claro... he mencionado aposta lo del tiempo transcurrido, porque he visto ya algunos (la mayoría son nuevos participantes) que a la media hora contestan similar para no decir igual... ya al menos tenemos una referencia al respecto.. saludos :)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con todo. Quizás no es tan oportuna la analogía con [Puzzling.SE]... Soy de priorizar la calidad por sobre todo el resto, y ahí no creo que debamos intentar llegar a una norma, sino más bien confiar en el sentido común. Al fin y al cabo, el autor de la pregunta va a elegir la que le plazca.

Comment: @Mariano hahah ya me advirtieron diciendo que no te gustaria esa parte de mi respuesta.